# How to save contents as html from any url

Tags: php

My question is that how can we save some html page for given url.. like if I will put the url "http://www.google.com/" then how we will save this page as html on server via php... the purpose is to read that page with utf-8 charset.. the current charset is windows-1255.. and I want to change the chrset to utf-8 or if there is any option to read that page with current charset when there is some other language in that page...

Actually I wana read the contents after search done.. of this page "http://elyon1.court.gov.il/verdictssearch/HebrewVerdictsSearch.aspx"

If there is any solution....

I m using PHP for serverside language..

Comment: `file_get_contents()` followed by `mb_convert_encoding()`?

Comment: Apparently, *URL's* need to shave too!

Answer (score 3):

You can save the contents with file_get_contents:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://elyon1.court.gov.il/verdictssearch/HebrewVerdictsSearch.aspx');
```

And then convert the charset with iconv:

```
$converted_page = iconv('windows-1252','utf-8',$page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is 'windows-1251' encoded page
$remote_page = 'http://www.gramota.ru/'; 

$doc = file_get_contents($remote_page);

// to get 'UTF-8' encoded content
$docutf8 = mb_convert_encoding($doc, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1251');
```

to show original document in original encoding (`windows-1251`)...

```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
  echo $doc;
```

to show original document in `UTF-8` encoding (converted from `windows-1251`)...

```
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  echo $docutf8;
```

Comment: I wanna submit 2 parameters to this page with post method before reading the page contents...

Comment: Edit your question please. I can't see that in title or question description. Question was about getting remote content and changing encoding charset.

Comment: I did mention there this thing but was not much clear it is "Actually I wana read the contents after search done.. of this page 'http://elyon1.court.gov.il/verdictssearch/HebrewVerdictsSearch.aspx'"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/i-want-to-read-the-contents-via-php-after-search-query-done